# xstream parser error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Tags: java, xstream

Let me start by saying this is the first time I am trying to use xStream.  I am trying to parse an xml file and use the data to build a java object.  I've added the xstream-1.4.4.jar, xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar,  xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar, and the kxml2-2.3.0.jar to my build paths.  I've tried to follow several tutorials, but just can't seem to figure out why I am receiving this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.FastStack.pop(FastStack.java:42)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.move(AbstractPullReader.java:125)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.moveDown(AbstractPullReader.java:103)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.XppReader.<init>(XppReader.java:63)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractXppDriver.createReader(AbstractXppDriver.java:54)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:913)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:904)
    at ParseTesting.Testing.main(Testing.java:10)
```

The xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<vblock>
    <name>vBlock1</name>
    <status>online</status>
    <storage>2.2</storage>
    <cpu>2.5</cpu>
</vblock>
```

Now, here is the corresponding class for the object I'd like to create:

```
package ParseTesting;

public class Vblock {
    private String name;
    private String status;
    private double storage;
    private double cpu;

    /*public Vblock(String n, String stat, double stor, double proc){
        name = n;
        status = stat;
        storage = stor;
        cpu = proc;
    }*/

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    public String getStatus(){
        return this.status;
    }
    public double getStorage(){
        return this.storage;
    }
    public double getCpu(){
        return this.cpu;
    }

}
```

And finally, the actually parsing that I am attempting:

```
package ParseTesting;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;

public class Testing {
    public static XStream xstream = new XStream();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        xstream.alias("vblock", Vblock.class);  
        Vblock v1 = (Vblock)xstream.fromXML("vBlock.xml");

        System.out.println(v1.getName());
    }

}
```

I would appreciate any insight that can be provided.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fromXML` method that takes a `String` parameter expects a string containing the actual XML you want to unmarshal, not a string containing the name of a file.  If you want to parse from a file you need to use one of the other `fromXML` methods taking a `File`, `URL` or `InputStream`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here.  I see that those methods exist, but I don't know how to pass a File, Url, or Inputstream.  How would I create a file object?

Answer (score 0):

@Ian

Never mind!  I did just what you told me to do.  The result looks a little something like this:

```
FileReader r = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\visualMonitor\\vBlock.xml");
        xstream.alias("vblock", Vblock.class);
        Vblock v1 = (Vblock)xstream.fromXML(r);
```

That is perfect.  Thank you!

Comment: While this will be OK for the specific file you've given in the question, be warned that a `FileReader` will only work in general if the character encoding of the XML file is the same as the default encoding on your platform.  It's generally much better to use the `fromXML` that takes a `File` or an `InputStream` rather than the one that takes a `Reader`, so the XML parser can detect and use the correct encoding for the file - `xstream.fromXML(new File("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\visualMonitor\\vBlock.xml"))`